# How are layers stored in PDF

Tags: pdf, layer, ocg

In PDF everything is in the format of /name.
I couldn't find a /Layers throughout the document.
If I want to look for all the layers what key should I look for?

Comment: What do you mean by layers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDF layers are formally known as "Optional Content Groups" and are described in section 4.10 of the [PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf). The object types you should be looking for are 'OCG' for a simple group or 'OCMD' for a more complex dictionary.